# Can I use ESP32 as a proxy to connect BLE device to AWS IoT cloud?

Tags: esp32, aws-iot, bluetooth-low-energy

Reading AWS IoT documentation I see that the proxy could only be an Android or iOS device.

To be more precise I’d like to publish from BLE (nRF52840) To AWS IoT using MQTT, but this device doesn’t have wifi connection, so I’d like to use ESP32 for this (ESP32 would act as a hub, with more BLE devices connected to it). Both devices are able to run Amazon FreeRTOS. This solutions seems natural and obvious, but I haven’t seen Amazon mentioning this anywhere in documentation.

Comment: "connect BLE device to AWS IoT cloud" is pretty vague.  What specifically are you trying to do?  IoT devices can communicate to AWS IoT cloud via MQTT, so general communication is definitely possible.  You can also run Amazon FreeRTOS on the ESP32 as well.

Comment: To be more precise I’d like to publish from BLE (nRF52840) To AWS IoT using MQTT, but this device doesn’t have wifi connection, so I’d like to use ESP32 for this (ESP32 would act as a hub, with more BLE devices connected to it). Both devices are able to run Amazon FreeRTOS. This solutions seems natural and obvious, but I haven’t seen Amazon mentioning this anywhere in documentation.

Comment: ESP32 can communicate with AWS IoT, and it can communicate over BLE.  However from a purist standpoint, you would need MQTT-SN for the Bluetooth side and have the ESP32 act as a MQTT-SN gateway to forward to AWS IoT.  It *might* be possible, but I don't know if you could fit all that on the ESP32.  Check out the [MQTT-SN gateway code on paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/components/mqtt-sn-transparent-gateway/)

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include your comment? "`To be more precise I’d like to ...`"

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica done

Comment: Thanks @JohnS good trace. I've dig deeper and found 2 possible solutions, which I will explore:
1. https://youtu.be/PBYCG-ypvRY
2. https://github.com/1technophile/OpenMQTTGateway